# Cardinalities of an extension to a theory

Tags: model-theory, quantifier-elimination

I have a universal first order universal theory T such that:

-T is universal over a finite language L

-T has a model completion T ⊆ T*

-T* is countable, has quantifier elimination (QE) and is complete.

Now considering a theory T ⊆ T' over L, suppose T' has QE. Can we say that T' is (at most) countable? If so, are there any assumptions I can drop and T' will still be countable? Alternatively, if not, are there any assumptions I could *add* to guarantee T' will be countable?

Thanks.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you give some more information about the motivation for your question? Since *every* theory $T$ has an extension $T'$ (in a larger language, but of the same cardinality) such that $T'$ has QE, *every* theory has extensions with QE of all infinite cardinalities.

Comment: A general comment: A frequent pattern is that someone asks "Is P true?" with no motivation attached, when P is obviously false. Then the only possible answer is "No, P is false." But often there's an interesting question (or a major misconception, or both!) hiding there, which is only revealed when the asker explains *why* they want to know if P is true. Explaining your motivation will make people more interested in answering your questions, and it will lead to much more useful answers for you!

Comment: @AlexKruckman apologies, I'm keeping it vague on purpose. The motivation is specifically the theory of equivalence realtions (contains one binary relation symbol) and its model completion (infinitely many eq. classes, all of them infinite), but I'm curious about the general case as well. The language of the (hypothetical) theory T' is the same as the original one and its model completion.

Comment: Oh! If the language is the same (and you've specified that the language of $T$ is finite), then of course $T'$ is countable, since there are only countably many sentences in a finite (or countable) language!

Comment: By the way, if $L = \{E\}$ and $T$ is the $L$-theory asserting that $E$ is an equivalence relation, I can explicitly list for you all of the $L$-theories $T'$ extending $T$ which have quantifier elimination (there are only countably many such theories). If you ask a new question on that topic, I'm happy to write this as an answer, with proof (unless, of course, this is homework or a problem you've been assigned to work out on your own).